# C++ user input to string array infinite loop

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I'm trying to parse a user input string into an array. `Example: user inputs "hello to you" array[0]="hello" array[1]="to" array[2]="you'` After I prompt the user to input some words, the program seems to infinitely loop. I have also tried using a vector, so it may be my logic in another area. I'm very rusty when it comes to the C language, so please excuse my ignorance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct FATNode;
struct FileNode;
class FileList;

class FAT
{
    FATNode* head;

};

class FileList
{
    FileNode* head;

    //methods
    public: 
        int createfile()
        {
            string word[2];
            cout << "Please input file name, followed by file size: ";

            int i = 0;
            for (string input; cin >> input; i++)
                    word[i] = input;

            for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                cout << word[i] << ' ';
            return 0;
        }

};

struct FileNode
{
    string filename;
    int filesize;
    FAT t1;
    FileNode* next;
};

struct FATNode
{
    int sectornumber;
    FATNode* next;
};

main()
{
    FileList myFileSystem;
    char start;
    int cmd;
    bool cont = true;

    while(cont == true)
    {
        cout << "Initializing disk.\n" << "To access menu, type 'Y'. To exit, type 'N': ";
        cin >> start;

        if(start == 'y' || start == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "What command would you like to execute on the disk?" << endl;
            cout << "1. Format disk\n2. Create file\n3. Delete file\n";
            cout << "4. List\n5. Read file\n6. Overwrite file\n7. Append to file\n8. Disk status\nSelection: ";
            cin >> cmd; 

            switch(cmd)
            {   
                case 1 :
                    break;
                case 2 :
                        myFileSystem.createfile();
                    break; 
                default :
                        cout << "Invalid command" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(start == 'n' || start == 'N')
        {
            cont = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to input a line of text, use `std::getline`.  Alternatively, make your loop terminate (and not overflow the array) by adding `i<2`.  i.e. `for (string input; i < 2 && cin >> input; i++)`

Comment: Maybe you should use a debugger to look into the behavior of your program around the position where you expect the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in your posted code that matches your question. It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop condition is `cin >> input`. This expression returns `cin`, which can be implicitly converted into a boolean (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). However, `cin` only becomes `false`, if there's an error or if you have reached end of file (`EOF`). You can signal `EOF` by pressing Ctrl+D.

Note also, that you are using a fixed-size array to store information that you get from the user. That's bad, because if the user enters more than 2 words, the array `word` will overflow. That's undefined behaviour.

If you just want a file name, followed by a file size, why don't you just use:

```
std::string filename;
std::size_t filesize;
std::cin >> filename >> filesize;
```

Comment: The instructor wanted us to use an array to store the variables, for some reason. I'm just going with this method though, because it seems more like what would happen in the real world. Thanks for your help!!